# How to creat connection websocket qxbroker in python

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, cloudflare

how to bypass HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in connect to wss://ws2.qxbroker.com/socket.io/EIO=3&transport=websocket, i try change user-agent and try use proxy and  add cookis but not work

```py
class WebsocketClient(object):


    def __init__(self, api):
        websocket.enableTrace(True)
        Origin = 'Origin: https://qxbroker.com'
        Extensions = 'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits'
        Host = 'Host: ws2.qxbroker.com'
        Agent = 'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/94.0.0.0'
       
        self.api = api
        self.wss=websocket.WebSocketApp(('wss://ws2.qxbroker.com/socket.io/EIO=3&transport=websocket'), on_message=(self.on_message),
          on_error=(self.on_error),
          on_close=(self.on_close),
          on_open=(self.on_open),
          header=[Origin,Extensions,Agent])
```

request and response header this site protect with cloudflare

```
--- request header ---
GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Host: ws2.qxbroker.com
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 7DgEjWxUp8N8PVY7N7vyDw==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Connection: Upgrade
Origin: https://qxbroker.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36
-----------------------
--- response header ---
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Sat, 11 Feb 2023 23:33:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Permissions-Policy: accelerometer=(),autoplay=(),camera=(),clipboard-read=(),clipboard-write=(),fullscreen=(),geolocation=(),gyroscope=(),hid=(),interest-cohort=(),magnetometer=(),microphone=(),payment=(),publickey-credentials-get=(),screen-wake-lock=(),serial=(),sync-xhr=(),usb=()
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Set-Cookie: __cf_bm=7TD4hk4.bntJRdP6w9K.AjXF5MsV9LERTJV00jL2Uww-1676158391-0-AZFOKw90ZYdyy4RxX1xJ4jZQMt74+3UkQDZpDrdXE8BxGJULfe8j0T8EZnpUNXr2W3YHd/FxRoO/bPhKA2Dc0E0=; path=/; expires=Sun, 12-Feb-23 00:03:11 GMT; domain=.qxbroker.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
Server-Timing: cf-q-config;dur=6.9999950937927e-06
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 7980e3583b6a0785-MRS
```

Comment: I'm having this issue on connecting to this exact broker..have you solved it.. would I be able to contact you

Comment: yes contact me , i think i have this issue on connecting

Comment: Give me your discord or email we have to really talk because I've noticed something odd about this particular server.. discord would be better tho. heres mine just incase....             solicit*ping me biatch*#3494

Comment: Or email : abombshell9@gmail.com

Comment: discord killwa#4666

Comment: telegram https://t.me/KillwaSf

Comment: @villmo any solution on this problem? I'm facing the same issue :(

Comment: @ManoelStilpen how far have you gone?.you on discord?

Comment: @Exboy check it out if there's a invite on your inbox. If not try adding me: manoelstilpen

Comment: Ok bro there isnt a # tho .. isn't this discord @ManoelStilpen

Answer (score 2):

i resolved the problem sending "header" parameter = {
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey bro I have a question about this as well

Answer (score 0):

Sending cookies in websocketapp argument?

"__cf_bm=7TD4hk4.bntJRdP6w9K.AjXF5MsV9LERTJV00jL2Uww-1676158391-0-AZFOKw90ZYdyy4RxX1xJ4jZQMt74+3UkQDZpDrdXE8BxGJULfe8j0T8EZnpUNXr2W3YHd/FxRoO/bPhKA2Dc0E0=; path=/; expires=Sun, 12-Feb-23 00:03:11 GMT; domain=.qxbroker.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

after my testing in qxbroker  websokcet i find the websocket need user-agent and cookies
to work

so your code will be like this

```
class WebsocketClient(object):


def __init__(self, api):
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    Origin = 'Origin: https://qxbroker.com'
    Extensions = 'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits'
    Host = 'Host: ws2.qxbroker.com'
    Agent = 'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/94.0.0.0'
    cookies= '_cfuvid=mWuH_0wX7ncTgDjTrfemYKnPcjPI7V6uaGHN9ApEyzQ-1695367118727-0-604800000; __cf_bm=1mCw3QsLAsOTN4wvLLUJVCLldhbAWXFLX4R9.ZtjvY8-1695373004-0-Af7UykiUoV8cRcoBDg7vvo8sZOi6ljCKa6VC8CfD/MEXeBFXlx48V3OUxX4Ascchvn7RvigBoflzuVm8s+Rt6Ew='
    self.api = api
    self.wss=websocket.WebSocketApp(('wss://ws2.qxbroker.com/socket.io/EIO=3&transport=websocket'), on_message=(self.on_message),
      on_error=(self.on_error),
      on_close=(self.on_close),
      on_open=(self.on_open),
      header=[Origin,Extensions,Agent])
```

`
or like that simple

```
import websocket as wb


headers={

    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0',
                        
    'Cookie': '_cfuvid=mWuH_0wX7ncTgDjTrfemYKnPcjPI7V6uaGHN9ApEyzQ-1695367118727-0-604800000; __cf_bm=1mCw3QsLAsOTN4wvLLUJVCLldhbAWXFLX4R9.ZtjvY8-1695373004-0-Af7UykiUoV8cRcoBDg7vvo8sZOi6ljCKa6VC8CfD/MEXeBFXlx48V3OUxX4Ascchvn7RvigBoflzuVm8s+Rt6Ew='
                            
            }
ws = wb.create_connection(f"wss://ws2.qxbroker.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket",header=headers)
```

**Note that maybe the cf_bm is the proplem so replace it with new one or all  both cookie**

Comment: I NEED  to have a chat with you.. I currently have this issue..please send your code.. you have telegram or discord sir?

Comment: @Exboy give me ur telegram

Comment: or text me ->@WW0BB